# mv-apply causes the value of ingestion_time() to be blanked out

Tags: azure-data-explorer

When you use mv-apply, ingestion_time() no longer has a value.
This makes it excessively difficult in some cases.

For example, if a function uses mv-apply to do some processing,
the consumer of the function can no longer use ingestion_time() to quickly filter down to recent rows ingested.

We can't use the workaround of 'project-rename' to expose the value, because project-rename won't work on ingestion_time()

Answer (score 3):

Once you apply `mv-apply` / `mv-expand`, the data is no longer 'attached' to a data shard, and therefore `ingestion_time()` becomes `null`.

Instead of running:

```
T
| mv-expand d // or `mv-apply ...`
| extend ingestion_time()
```

you should run:

```
T
| extend ChooseAColumnName = ingestion_time() 
| mv-expand d // or `mv-apply ...`
```

Comment: This workaround doesn't work from a perf perspective, because the optimizer can't use the underlying optimizations on ingestion_time().
Compare these:

`ReallyBigTableFoo
| where ingestion_time()>ago(1h) 
| count`

>> Really fast


`let bar=() {
ReallyBigTableFoo
| extend IngestionTime=ingestion_time()
| mv-apply ...
};
bar
| where IngestionTime >= ago(1h)
| count`

// Query timed out after 4 minutes.

Comment: The workaround for any regular column is fine since we can use project-rename. But we are stuck with ingestion_time. Any function using mv-apply thus can't be effectively filtered on using the ingestion_time of the table, which is critical in case of a watermark for exporting to a downstream system.

Comment: 1. If performance is of highest priority, you can consider performing the `mv-expand` at ingestion time, using an update policy, to not have to perform it at query runtime. 2. Instead of using `ingestion_time()` as a means for "exactly once" processing, you should be using the database cursor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databasecursor